# Nodejs Multiple pools created on refresh

Tags: node.js, oracle, promise, connection-pooling

I have several DBs for which i am using connection pools in node.js. Every time i refresh page i think pools are created again. i refresh page 3 times and 3 times promises resolved. i have removed several databases just to make it little bit easier to read here.
[image]

and if i un-comment connection close line my app crashes. i can't seem to figure out why

[image]

```js
const config = require("../config/config");
const oracledb = require("oracledb");

var crm1connPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    oracledb.createPool({
        user: config.crm1.user,
        password: config.crm1.password,
        connectString: config.crm1.connectString,
        poolAlias: config.crm1.poolAlias,
        poolMin: 0,
        poolMax: 10,
        poolTimeout: 300
    }, (error, pool) => {
        if (error) {
            reject(err);
        }
        resolve("CRM1 Promise resolved")
    });
});

var query2connPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    oracledb.createPool({
        user: config.query2.user,
        password: config.query2.password,
        connectString: config.query2.connectString,
        poolAlias: config.query2.poolAlias,
        poolMin: 0,
        poolMax: 10,
        poolTimeout: 300
    }, (error, pool) => {
        if (error) {
            reject(err);
        }
        resolve("QUERY2 Promise resolved --------")
    });
});

var promiseArray = [crm1connPromise, crm2connPromise, crm3connPromise, crm4connPromise, csfp1connPromise, csfp2connPromise, csfp3connPromise, csfp4connPromise, cact1connPromise, cact2connPromise, cact3connPromise, cact4connPromise, cospconnPromise, cchnconnPromise, bbaseconnPromise, bcdrconnPromise, vcdbconnPromise, crptconnPromise, query2connPromise];

function getDBConnection (dbname) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            Promise.all(promiseArray).then((message) => {
                console.log(message);
                const pool = oracledb.getPool(dbname);
                pool.getConnection( (err, connection) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    resolve(connection);
                });
            });

        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }

    });
}

module.exports.query = function(dbname, sql, bind = []){
    return new Promise ((resolve,reject) =>{
        var conn
        try {
            getDBConnection(dbname).then((connection) =>{
                connection.execute(sql,bind,(err,result)=>{
                    if (err){
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(result);
                })
                //connection.close(0);
            })
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This code is very hard to understand. First, `crm1connPromise` and `query2connPromise` have no real value add since the driver's methods already return promises. Second, why would you add initialization code paths to your run time code `Promise.all(promiseArray)`? Have a look through this series on creating a REST API with Node.js: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/ Note that the application initialization code is done first and is separate from the runtime use of the pools.

Comment: Finally, now that async/await is a thing, you should learn to use it instead of explicit promises (only use those when needed). See the links at the bottom of this post to learn about the progression of async patterns: https://jsao.io/2017/06/how-to-get-use-and-close-a-db-connection-using-various-async-patterns/

Comment: Looking closer at your promise array, I can see there are 19 elements - that's wild. Are you starting up 19 connection pools? If so, do you have 19 different databases, or are they mostly different users on the same database?

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'Singleton'

please google 'Singleton pattern' and examples.

like this:

dataBaseManager.js:

```
'use strict'

var Singleton = (function () {
    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new dataBaseManager();
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

function dataBaseManager() {
    this.connected = false;
    this.client = null;
    this.dataBase = null;

    //public methods
    this.connect = function () {
        try {

            your_database.connect({}, (err, client) => {
                if (err) {
                    this.connected = false;
                    this.client = null;
                    this.dataBase = null;
                    return;
                }
                this.connected = true;
                this.client = client;
                this.dataBase = client.db();
            });

        } catch (error) {

        }
    };
    this.disconnect = function () {
        try {
            if (this.client) {
                this.client.close();
                this.connected = false;
                this.client = null;
                this.dataBase = null;
            }

        } catch (error) {

        }
    }
}

module.exports = Singleton;
```

repository.js:

```
const dataBaseManager = require("./dataBaseManager").getInstance();

your_get_dample_data_from_data_base_func = function (data) {
  dataBaseManager.dataBase
    .find({})
    .toArray(function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err, null);
      }
      callback(null, result);
    });
};
```

index.js:

```
const dataBaseManager = require("./dataBaseManager").getInstance();

function connect() {
  dataBaseManager.connect();
}

function disconnect() {
  dataBaseManager.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the node-oracledb example [webappawait.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/webappawait.js) which starts the pool outside the web listener code path.

```
async function init() {
  try {
    await oracledb.createPool({
      user: dbConfig.user,
      password: dbConfig.password,
      connectString: dbConfig.connectString
     });

    const server = http.createServer();
    server.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log('HTTP server problem: ' + err);
    });
    server.on('request', (request, response) => {
      handleRequest(request, response);
    });
    await server.listen(httpPort);
    console.log("Server is running at http://localhost:" + httpPort);

  } catch (err) {
    console.error("init() error: " + err.message);
  }
}


async function handleRequest(request, response) {

 . . .

}
```